# html table <td> width in repeater itemtemplate unable to set

Tags: html, asp.net, html-table, repeater

I'm trying to adjust the width of the columns in the HTML table which act as the holder of ASP repeater items.

```
<asp:Repeater id="viewproduct" runat="server"> 
 <HeaderTemplate>
  <table id="grid">
    <thead >
       <tr>
         <th width="20px" data-field="check"></th>
         <th data-field="level">Status</th>
         <th data-field="Class">Username</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>``
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
      <tr>
      <td width="20px"><asp:CheckBox ID="CheckApprove" runat="server" Width="20px" /></td>                   
      <td><asp:Label ID="status" runat="server"
            Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Status")%>'></asp:Label></td> 
      <td><asp:Label ID="name" runat="server"
            Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "name")%>'></asp:Label></td>
      </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Notice that the header follows the width, but the content does not. WHY?
Here's how my table looks like currently:

[image]

Comment: Why not set it with CSS.

Comment: Can you show us a relevant snippet of your resulting HTML?

Comment: From the image it _seems_ like you are not showing us _all_ the code. It looks like there is at least one more column to the right of UserName. I am only mentioning this because if there is more to your table, it may help us find the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Use style tag in th and td
<asp:Repeater id="viewproduct" runat="server"> 
 <HeaderTemplate>
  <table id="grid">
    <thead >
       <tr>
         <th style="width:20px;" data-field="check"></th>
         <th data-field="level">Status</th>
         <th data-field="Class">Username</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>``
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
      <tr>
      <td style="width:20px;" ><asp:CheckBox ID="CheckApprove" runat="server" Width="20px" /></td>                   
      <td><asp:Label ID="status" runat="server"
            Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Status")%>'></asp:Label></td> 
      <td><asp:Label ID="name" runat="server"
            Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "name")%>'></asp:Label></td>
      </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `style="width:20px;"` instead of  `width="20px"`